# R ggplot: How do I manually set geom_ribbon colours?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is some data:

```
df2 <- structure(list(grp = c("grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp2", "grp2", 
"grp2"), sec = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), mean = c(5, 6, 7, 15, 16, 
17), sem = c(0.307763139524895, 0.308898539869074, 0.307764922272404, 
0.308130848924571, 0.308548696579921, 0.30907120414686)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fb90600cee0>)
```

It is a time series, which I am plotting using ggplot with:

```
ggplot (df2, aes(x=sec, y=mean, group=grp, colour=grp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=mean-sem, ymax=mean+sem, fill=grp), colour=NA)
```

I want to manually set the ribbon colours per group. Only the ribbon, so not changing the line colour. Sounds obvious but I cannot find any way to do it.

I have tried adding `scale_fill_manual` and/or `scale_colour_manual` like:

```
ggplot (df2, aes(x=sec, y=mean, group=grp, colour=grp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=mean-sem, ymax=mean+sem, fill=grp), colour=NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red', 'black')) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('green', 'yellow'))
```

It does change the ribbon colour, but also the line (or plots the ribbon on top I am not sure, but not helpful either way).

Here is roughly the behaviour I want:

[image]

Comment: Just change the order in which you are adding layers, add the `geom_ribbon` first, then add the `geom_line` so it's drawn on top.

Comment: Geez, it was that obvious. Thank you. Happy to accept it as answer if you put it below.

Comment: Ah, then another issue comes up when traces overlap. The trace of group 2 (for instance) ends up in the ribbon of group 1. Ideally I'd want each group's trace + ribbon to be plotted on separate layers. Any idea?

Comment: Make your ribbons somewhat transparent with an `alpha=` parameter. Then you can see if they overlap.

Comment: Yes, I know that's what I should do. The reason I am not is: I'm exporting in eps with `ggsave` and R does not want to export the whole plot's background as transparent + the ribbon as semi-transparent. It just ends up not drawing the ribbon. Anyway, that's beyond the scope of my question.